# AWK match exact value from comma separated column in brackets

Tags: linux, awk, regular-expression

So I need to find an exact number match from one column in a file.  The input files is similar to the following:

```
33.xx  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,22,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
24.1b  1131  0 0 0 some+text1 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [1,25,22] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
1.52  1211  0 0 0 some+text3 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [22,2,123] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
```

I want to match only lines that would have `22` as one of the values between the brackets and output the first column.

Comment: What is desired output and what you are trying?

Comment: You should have included some lines that do not match and some that contain `222` in the matching field, plus the expected output. With just those 3 sunny day lines and no expected output we can't test if a potential solution works or not.

Comment: Particular concern regarding column 6: free text could be blank, multiword, or contain `[ `or `]` characters (for example) any of which would break most solutions relying on field numbering or FS settings. I would parse from the end of the line backwards, as that date/time ending appears to be much more stable. Splitting `$(NF - 2)` using `[^[:digit:]]+` might be sufficiently general.

Comment: If you add a test case where `some+text` is actually `this is [22] fun` such as `33.xx  1111  0 0 0 this is [22] fun 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234` then most suggested solutions will fail. It's always much easier to match the text you want to match than to not match similar text you don't want to match - you really have to come up with and provide the rainy day cases in your example if you want a robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '$(NF-2) ~ /[[,]22[],]/{print $1}' file
33.xx
24.1b
1.52
```

With some more comprehensive sample input that includes more than just the sunny day cases where we find a match where we expect to find a match:

```
$ cat file
33.xx  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,22,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
24.1b  1131  0 0 0 some+text1 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [1,25,22] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
1.52  1211  0 0 0 some+text3 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [22,2,123] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.123
1.good  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [22] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
2.good  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,22] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
3.good  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [22,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
4.good  1111  0 0 0 foo bar 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,22,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
5.bad  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
6.bad  1111  0 0 0 some+text 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,222,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
7.bad  1111  0 0 0 this is [22] fun 12:12:12.9999  9999:090909 88 [11,33] 2020-12-12 12:12:12.1234
```

here is the output it produces which I think is probably what the OP would expect:

```
$ awk '$(NF-2) ~ /[[,]22[],]/{print $1}' file
33.xx
24.1b
1.52
1.good
2.good
3.good
4.good
```

I'm using `$(NF-2)` to count fields from the end rather than the beginning of each line so it'll work no matter what `some+text` actually contains. If `some+text` never contains white space then you could use `$10` instead of `$(NF-2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -o1 '(\S*).*(\[(\d+,)*22(,\d+)*])' file
```

---

Using `awk`:

The following command may be used:

```
$ nawk '$(NF-2) ~ /\[([[:alnum:]]*,)*22(,[[:alnum:]]*)*]/{print $1}' file
```

If alphabetical characters are not required then it may be changed to this command.

```
$ awk '$(NF-2) ~ /\[([[:digit:]]*,)*22(,[[:digit:]]*)*]/{print $1}' file
```

If missing values in brackets are not required then the following may be used.

```
$ awk '$(NF-2) ~ /\[([[:digit:]]+,)*22(,[[:digit:]]+)*]/{print $1}' file
```

Comment: Edited. And thanks @EdMorton

Comment: @ChrisDavies thanks for the explanation and verification! Prabhjot you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk -F"[][]" '$2~"22"{print }' <input file>
```

here the delimiter is set to be `[` or `]` and check if second field contain 22

If you want the value to be checked to be exactly 22 you can use something like:

```
awk -F"[][]" '$2~",22" || $2~"22,"{print }' <input file>
```

If you search for absolute strictness you can use something like:

```
awk -F"[][]" '{split($2,a,","); for (i in a) if(a[i]==22) {split($1,b," ");print b[1];break} }'   <input file>
```

Comment: This is part of the issue I have is I would then have to maybe pipe this output to another awk to split off and grab that first column which I would rather avoid.

Comment: @ScottNipp, this can be easy created, will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I take it that your are only interested in the first columns of the lines  that have the desired match. In that case here is a way that uses grep:

```
$ egrep '\[.*\,22,|\[22\,|\,22\]' infile.txt | cut  -d' ' -f1
33.xx
24.1b
1.52
```

infile.txt is the sample data shown in your question.